# Opening a new window from a parent window in IE clears parent window's cache

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser-cache

I have a web app that opens a new window when a link is clicked. As soon as I do that though, my browser's cache is cleared. If I do not click the link, the cache is still there.

I have tried both the standard `target="_blank"` and `window.open` approach and they both result in the cleared cache.

Here is a reference to someone else encountering the same issue, but with no solution.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/problem-new-window-clears-cache-t693284.html

Any idea as to why?

IE 7 and 8

Comment: How are you testing whether the cache is cleared?

Comment: Honestly, I am debugging the app and have a break point on the page_load of a previous page that should be cache.

Comment: Caching doesn't happen by default on dynamic content in IIS - are you returning the correct cache control headers?

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me, and I haven't seen any reports of similar issues. Are you able to reproduce this on another machine? Can you edit your post and list how you verified this, and why you've come this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, try out and let me know:

Html Page 1(Parent):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="wpop1.aspx.vb" Inherits="pruebas_wpop1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="PRIVATE" />
    <title>Parent</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <a href="wpop3.aspx" target="_blank" >Popup</a><br/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind Page 1:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load       

        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2D)
        Response.Expires = 7200
        Response.CacheControl = "PRIVATE"

End Sub
```

Html Page 2(PopUp):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="wpop3.aspx.vb" Inherits="pruebas_wpop3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">       
    <title>PopUp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    This is the Popup Window.
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is working for me on Internet Explorer 8.0 with the compatibility mode enabled and disabled.